# Trying to use data outside the onDataChange() in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in this ! Please can someone help me.
I know that here I am dealing with asynchronous programming, I am trying to return the String but it still returning null.

Can someone tell me where I am wrong.

```
public interface OnGetDataListener {
    public void onStart();
    public void onSuccess(DataSnapshot data);
    public void onFailed(DatabaseError databaseError);
}

public void mReadDataOnce(String email ,String child, final OnGetDataListener listener) {
    listener.onStart();
    myRef.child(email).child(child).limitToFirst(1).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            listener.onSuccess(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            listener.onFailed(databaseError);
        }
    });
}

private String mCheckInforInServer(String email ,String child) {
    final String[] returnvalue = new String[1];

    mReadDataOnce(email ,child, new OnGetDataListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            //DO SOME THING WHEN START GET DATA HERE
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DataSnapshot data) {
            returnvalue[0] = data.getValue().toString();
            //DO SOME THING WHEN GET DATA SUCCESS HERE
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailed(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            //DO SOME THING WHEN GET DATA FAILED HERE
        }
    });

    return returnvalue[0] ;
}
```

Then I am calling it:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.i(" ","HIMANSHU" +  mCheckInforInServer("a","name"));
    Log.i(" ","HIMANSHU" +  mCheckInforInServer("a","email"));
}
```

Log is printing null, I want the values. Please help!

Comment: Please see my answer here where you can use the value from datasnapshot outside onDataChange https://stackoverflow.com/a/55741593/3904109

Answer (score 1):

Take a minute, try to read your code and understand it.

Inside the method `mCheckInforInServer()` the code gets executed in following sequence :

1. initialize `returnvalue`
2. create a anonymous instance of type `OnGetDataListener`.
3. pass this instance of type `OnGetDataListener` to `mReadDataOnce()` method and let this method use `OnGetDataListener` instance to change the value of `returnvalue` whenever it wants (which will take some time to complete since its using network with some latencies. This latency will be greater than the latency in execution of next 2 statements almost in 99.9999% cases)
4. since `mReadDataOnce()` operates asynchronously, the program control lets it go on and continue with the implementation of `mCheckInfoInServer()`
5. return the current value of, which in 0.0001% case will be the value that you need.

So, you just need to get to that 0.0001% case.

**Or**, you can ask your `mReadDataOnce()` to invoke a method inside your main-activity when it completes, which will be give you the value that you need in 99.9999% cases, if all goes well. You can try somthing like this :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mReadDataOnce("a" ,"email", new OnGetDataListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            //DO SOME THING WHEN START GET DATA HERE
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DataSnapshot data) {
            Log.i("", "HIMANSHU" +  data.getValue().toString());
            //DO SOME THING WHEN GET DATA SUCCESS HERE
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailed(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            //DO SOME THING WHEN GET DATA FAILED HERE
        }
    });
    mReadDataOnce("a" ,"email", new OnGetDataListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            //DO SOME THING WHEN START GET DATA HERE
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DataSnapshot data) {
             Log.i("", "HIMANSHU" +  data.getValue().toString());            
             //DO SOME THING WHEN GET DATA SUCCESS HERE
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailed(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            //DO SOME THING WHEN GET DATA FAILED HERE
        }
    });
}
```

**Update in the code:**

Actually, here I am trying to store value from the database to the Records Class.

```
public interface OnGetDataListener {
    public void onStart();
    public void onSuccess(DataSnapshot data);
    public void onFailed(DatabaseError databaseError);
}

public void mReadDataOnce(String email ,String child, final OnGetDataListener listener) {
    listener.onStart();
    myRef.child(email).child(child).limitToFirst(1).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            listener.onSuccess(dataSnapshot);
            record.setName(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            listener.onFailed(databaseError);
        }
    });
}
```

And then retrieving the value from the Records class in onCreate()

```
mReadDataOnce("a" ,"email", new OnGetDataListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            //DO SOME THING WHEN START GET DATA HERE
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DataSnapshot data) {
            Log.i("", "HIMANSHU" +  data.getValue().toString());
            record.setName(data.getValue().toString());
            //DO SOME THING WHEN GET DATA SUCCESS HERE
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailed(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            //DO SOME THING WHEN GET DATA FAILED HERE
        }
    });

    Log.i(" ","HIMANSHUKUSHWAHA"+record.getName());
    //Printing null
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am trying to access the returned value outside the  mReadDataOnce() method in onCreate().

Comment: so for example, you want to use that data in a method called `doSomethin()` inside the main-activtiy. Then, you can simply call `doSomething(data)` inside implementation of `OnGetDataListener#onSuccess()`

Comment: Did you really read my answer ? and the code that I have added in the ans ?